# Transforming list-columns in tibbles, using "intersect" in this case

Tags: r, list, tidyverse, stringr

How can I perform functions on character vectors embedded in a list column of a tibble in R?

The concept is that I have merged 2 data sets that both include a free text field for an address, and I would like to calculate how many words of each free text field are common.  I will explore fuzzy logic but would also like to find a solution to this problem.

For example, consider this code:

```
require(tidyverse)    

df <- tibble(
      x = c("one two three four", "two three four five"), 
      y = c("three four five six", "four five six seven")
    )

df.lst <- df %>% 
  mutate(x.lst = str_extract_all(x, "[:alnum:]+"),
         y.lst = str_extract_all(y, "[:alnum:]+")) %>% 
  glimpse()

# Observations: 2
# Variables: 4
# $ x     <chr> "one two three four", "two three four five"
# $ y     <chr> "three four five six", "four five six seven"
# $ x.lst <list> [<"one", "two", "three", "four">, <"two", "three", "four", "...
# $ y.lst <list> [<"three", "four", "five", "six">, <"four", "five", "six", "...

df.lst %>% 
  mutate(xy.x = intersect(x.lst, y.lst))

#    Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
 #     Column `xy.x` must be length 2 (the number of rows) or one, not 0
```

I have tried using `Reduce(intersect...` without success.

I have considered setting up a new tibble with the list columns flattened but I would prefer to keep the structure with 1 row per record pair given that the strings are relatively short.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `map2` from the [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) package to loop through two lists with `intersect`. The result can be stored in a new column (`Compare` in this case).

```
library(tidyverse)

df.lst2 <- df.lst %>%
  mutate(Compare = map2(x.lst , y.lst, ~intersect(.x, .y)))

df.lst2$Compare
# [[1]]
# [1] "three" "four" 
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "four" "five"
```

**Update**

We can also use `rowwise` with `mutate` as the other post suggested. But for large data frames, `rowwise` may slow down the performance of the `intersect` function. Here I used the `microbenchmark` package to evaluate these two methods on a large data frame (10000 rows) with the same structure with `df.lst`.

```
library(microbenchmark)

# Create a large data frame
df_large <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:10000,
  x = df$x,
  y = df$y,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df_large <- df_large %>% 
  select(-ID) %>%
  as.tibble()

df_large.lst <- df_large %>%
  mutate(x.lst = str_extract_all(x, "[:alnum:]+"),
         y.lst = str_extract_all(y, "[:alnum:]+")) %>% 
  glimpse() 
# Observations: 10,000
# Variables: 4
# $ x     <chr> "one two three four", "two three four five", "one two three four", "two three...
# $ y     <chr> "three four five six", "four five six seven", "three four five six", "four fi...
# $ x.lst <list> [<"one", "two", "three", "four">, <"two", "three", "four", "five">, <"one", ...
# $ y.lst <list> [<"three", "four", "five", "six">, <"four", "five", "six", "seven">, <"three...

# Performance Evaluation
perm <- microbenchmark(
  m1 = {df_large.lst2 <- df_large.lst %>%
    mutate(xy.x = map2(x.lst , y.lst, ~intersect(.x, .y)))},
  m2 = {df_large.lst2 <- df_large.lst %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(xy.x = list(intersect(x.lst, y.lst))) %>%
    ungroup()},
  m3 = {df_large.lst2 <- df_large.lst%>%
      rownames_to_column () %>%
      group_by(rowname) %>%
      mutate(xy.x =list(intersect(unlist(x.lst),unlist(y.lst))))},
  times = 100L
)

perm
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#   m1 158.8871 171.7935 183.0220 176.3373 191.0863 260.3079   100
#   m2 353.1279 387.1014 405.2522 401.6800 422.6556 459.7453   100
#   m3 436.0175 465.9106 496.4585 481.7983 527.7079 613.0461   100
```

Comment: Thanks so much www. I tried using purrr and map2 but obviously didn't get my head around the syntax. I'm so appreciative!

Comment: Can you try running the benchmark on the one below?

Answer (score 1):

```
s=df.lst%>%
     rowwise()%>%
     mutate(xy.x=list(intersect(x.lst,y.lst)))

s$xy.x
[[1]]
[1] "three" "four" 

[[2]]
[1] "four" "five"
```

You can also use `group_by`

```
df.lst%>%
    group_by_(names(df.lst))%>%
    mutate(mm=list(intersect(unlist(x.lst),unlist(y.lst))))
s1$mm
[[1]]
[1] "three" "four" 

[[2]]
[1] "four" "five"
```

If you feel that maybe at one point you can have two rows with very similar quantities, then do:

```
 df.lst%>%
    rownames_to_column%>%
    group_by(rowname)%>%
    mutate(mm=list(intersect(unlist(x.lst),unlist(y.lst))))


Now if you do the microbench on the last one as compared to the other two:

perm
Unit: milliseconds
 expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max   neval
   m1 333.607625 354.065554 425.308486 374.658775  514.01087  818.6467    100
   m2 810.377360 842.860575 970.846458 878.892835 1074.33373 1329.3056    100
   m3   3.179928   3.323983   4.241713   3.799968    4.49567   20.0653    100
```

So after running the microbench on the large dataset, you will see that the group_by is way much quicker:

Comment: Good thinking to use group_by if there are duplicates in the data frame.

Comment: @www thats why i did give  a suggestion to use rowname.. there can not be duplicates..

Comment: And then `group_by` is not faster. It is just another version of `rowwise`. Based on the information you provided, it is likely that you performed the microbenchmarking for the original data frame, but not the large data frame. I have updated my microbenchmarking result.

Comment: @www Use the group by (names) thats what i did the microbench on. And i did on the large dataset. Otherwise m1 could not have a mean of 425. Try all the four methods provided above...you will notice the difference

Comment: And this back to my original point. `group_by_(names(.))` looks fast because you have duplicates, which means records with all columns are the same. I created the large dataset with duplicates just for convenience to show that `rowwise` operation would have performance issue. We would expect that the real word dataset have unique records. In this case, `group_by` would not be fast.

Comment: If at all there are duplicates then it wont work since the result would be different.. same results for different rows. But in our case there are no duplicates. Row 1 is completely different from row 2. Also. Duplicates should give similar results. Thus groupby is the best.

Comment: In my large data frame example, even rows are the same, and odd rows are the same. Your `group_by_(names(.))` solution is fast because of that. If there is a data frame with complete different elements per row, `group_by_(names(.))` will not be particularly fast.

Comment: I do understand now. Thanks